# Functionality for automatic retry after exception

Tags: java, android, error-handling, guava

I have made the following system to automatically retry network calls if some exception is thrown. (Earlier [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799001) on stackOverFlow, solution inspired by what @Boris answered)

```
public static <T> Optional<T> autoRetry(@NonNull final DoWork<T> task, @NonNull final Optional<Predicate<T>> resultRejector) {

        for (int retry = 0; retry <= StaticData.NETWORK_RETRY; ++retry) {

            try {

                Thread.sleep(retry * StaticData.NETWORK_CALL_WAIT);
                final T resultAfterWork = task.doWork();
                /**
                 * If the result was not
                 * desirable we RETRY.
                  */
                if(resultRejector.isPresent() && resultRejector.get().apply(resultAfterWork))
                    continue;
                /**
                 * Else we return
                 */
                return Optional.fromNullable(resultAfterWork);
            } catch (InterruptedException | UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); //To be replaced by proper logging
                return Optional.absent();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); //To be replaced by proper logging
            }
        }
        return Optional.absent();
    }
```

- I take care to not retry after InterruptedException &
  UnknownHostException.
- I retry 5 times. After each failure I perform an exponential back
  off, starting from 300ms going upto 1500ms.
- The predicate is used to verify the validity of the expected result.

The DoWork class :

```
public abstract class DoWork<T> {
    protected abstract T doWork() throws IOException;
}
```

I did not use Supplier because I need to throw an IOException.

Here is an example of how I use it. (this example updates the GCM Id)

//Context is android specific stuff, basically if app dies, reference will return null.

```
public static boolean updateGCM(final long id, final WeakReference<Context> reference) {

final String regId = autoRetry(new DoWork<String>() {
    @Override
    protected String doWork() throws IOException {

        final Context context = reference.get();
        if(context == null)
            return "QUIT";
        return GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context)
                .register("XXXXXXXXXX");
    }
}, Optional.<Predicate<String>>of(new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(@Nullable String input) {
        return TextUtils.isEmpty(input); //I need to retry if the returned GCM ID was null/empty
    }
})).orNull();
//Context becomes null when the application is exited
//If retires failed or application exited, we return
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(regId) || regId.equals("QUIT"))
    return false;

Log.i("Ayush", "Uploading newGcmId to server");
final Boolean result = autoRetry(new DoWork<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doWork() throws IOException {

        //if everything is fine, send id to server
        return true;
    }
}, Optional.<Predicate<Boolean>>absent()).orNull(); //No need of predicate hence send absent

return !(result == null || !result);
}
```

- So on a scale of 1 to 10 how professional is this approach ? :)
- Also I do not want to retry if the network is genuinely failing, like
  UnknownHostException, or something bad happens which wont get
  resolved with retrying. Any possibility of improving exception handling ?

Comment: Ever heard of the [CircuitBreaker Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html)?

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about this. There seems to be a [Java library](https://github.com/Comcast/jrugged) for this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static <T> Optional<T> autoRetry(@NonNull final DoWork<T> task, @NonNull final Optional<Predicate<T>> predicate) {
```

No `predicate`, please. Call it something like `acceptResult` or `resultRejector`... you know what I mean.

```
Thread.sleep(retry * StaticData.NETWORK_CALL_WAIT);
```

This doesn't do what you write, as the first time `retry=0`.

> I take care to not retry after InterruptedException & UnknownHostException.

The latter may be retryable as it may be a temporary network or DNS problem. But it's your choice.

```
final String regId = autoRetry(new DoWork<String>() {...
```

I'm too lazy to copy it in my Eclipse and without it, it's unreadable as I have no idea where the expressions ends. What about a `private final DoWork<String> regIdDoWork = ...` or alike?

```
Optional.<Predicate<Boolean>>absent()).orNull(); //No need of predicate hence send absent
```

How nicer would the world be if there was no `Optional`? :D Just `null`.

Note that even if you like `Optional`, you should probably use it for as return types only. This is the place where it may prevent bugs and where it doesn't add so much verbosity.

Comment: The first retry 0 is on purpose. As for your last point, I never had a problem with null, but the more exp people say null is ugly xD

Comment: @Dexter Yes, `null` is ugly, but not as ugly as `Optional`. YMMV, but I fully agree with [this rant](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/project-lombok/ROx9rGRb6lI/EF0lk8F0N10J). ;)

Comment: That's one hell of a rant. I like the idea of every type having a default null replacement value. But it does seem an even more herculean task.